# Ошибка в session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter

Tags: php

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Как исправить такую ошибку?

> `Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/u22691/domains/pokess.u-gu.ru/public_html/game/fight.php:1) in /home/u22691/domains/pokess.u-gu.ru/public_html/game/fight.php on line 2`

Comment: Что во второй строке в fight.php?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Видимо файл сохранен в кодировке utf-8 with bom, сохраняйте без bom.

Comment: Как так сохранить?))

Comment: notepad++ например

Answer (score 6):

> headers already sent

Ну блин почти же по-русски написано [link](http://translate.google.com/#en|ru|headers%20already%20sent)

Перед `session_start()` не должно быть никакого вывода на экран, даже пробела.

Comment: Ноль на массу! Я почему и спрашиваю..

Comment: Ну тогда проверьте кодировку, как сказал @tranceman

Answer (score 3):

Перед сессией ничего не должно быть напсано, а так же стоит посмотреть кодировку.
еще можно проверить файл php.ini

Answer (score 2):

типичная ошибка следующая:

```
<? 
код php
?>
```

и вот тут после ?> стоит любой символ. Из-за этого PHP сразу выдаст  header
И причем, эту ошибку легко пропустить, если есть include, где такая штука произошла.
Поэтому, лучше закрывающий ?> не писать, если у вас после него ничего нет.

Answer (score 2):

Проблема может быть не столь очевидна, если ты программируешь классами. Например ты описываешь
`session_start()` в главном файле с родительским классом. Там у тебя всё правильно написано: никаких выводов, никаких пробелов до начала сесии. Но при входе на сайт у тебя запускается файл потомок, то-есть почти всегда `index.php`. В тексте ошибки написана ссылка на ту строку, где объявлено начало сесии но проблема может быть и во всех файлах к которым ты подключаешь
родительский класс с вызовом `session_start()`. Поэтому во всех файлах где есть присоединение например чтото вроде этого

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/admin/'файл с session_start() функцией'.php');
class index extends название класса
```

Так вот до этих 2 строчек во всех файлах ничего не должно выводится. А вот после них - вполне возможно.

Answer (score -1):

Проблема может быть и в следующем случае.

К примеру форма на php встроена в HTML. Работает, всё нормально. далее что либо добавляете в HTML . . . и приехали, вылетает сообщение. Ни один из вариантов вверху не помогает, ни с сохранением без ВОМ, ничего . . . это происходит из - за разницы в кодировке текста, который добавляете при помощи копипаст . . . Любые попытки сохранения итогового текста в UTF-8 либо в ANSI не приведут к нормальной работе скрипта.

Выход - рабочий вариант странички с формой на php открываете в текстовом редакторе и вносите изменения вручную. Затем просто сохраняете без функции сохранить как! Всё будет работать без ошибок. Извиняюсь за слишком подробный мануал.

Comment: Кодировка текста не имеет никакого отношения к проблеме за исключением случаев когда редактор добавляет BOM.